# Buckets as column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Q: The column should be created based on the Occupation like Doctor, Teacher, Sweeper, Lawyer which will contain the names ordered alphabetically.

The table:

```
Name  | Occupation
------------------
Amex  |   Teacher
Joe   |   Lawyer
Colin |   Doctor
Fenny |  Sweeper
Lio   |  Doctor
James |  Teacher
Kevin |  Teacher
Megh  |  Lawyer
```

Output:

```
Colin  Amex Fenny Joe
Lio    James NULL Megh
NULL   Kevin NULL NULL
```

I have tried doing pivoting, bucketing and partitioning yet it's not working.

Comment: This is pivot query. Not implemented in MySQL. Emulate it. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pivot

Answer (score 0):

Static occupation list pivotting:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (PARTITION BY Occupation ORDER BY Name) rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Doctor' THEN Name END) AS Doctor,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Teacher' THEN Name END) AS Teacher,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Sweeper' THEN Name END) AS Sweeper,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Occupation = 'Lawyer' THEN Name END) AS Lawyer
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn
ORDER BY rn;
```

| Doctor | Teacher | Sweeper | Lawyer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Colin | Amex | Fenny | Joe |
| Lio | James | *null* | Megh |
| *null* | Kevin | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qiYUhyLh)